# Associate Shell Script to file extension

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

This may be a toughy or straight forward enough but trying to run a shell script every time a file is open to stop people accessing in use files. The file is in fused from a Google Cloud Storage bucket to a Ubuntu VM with a copy living in another bucket. When a user opens a file I want to run a shell script that sets the copy to read only. Anyone know a way or potential avenue I could  explore to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only way I can imagine is to create a loop that read a "ps axw" command and filters the output looking for the specific filename or extension, then extract the path in some way and chmod it to remove write permissions

Comment: This sounds vaguely like a job for source control. The best solution would involve understanding how the file is used that only one person should be editing it at a time.

Comment: hmmm not as elegant as I hoped. I was thinking of making an executable script myself and assocating all .example files to it. This executable would then run the read only command and then open the application I want   (example notepad) as default. Does this make sense? Basically the whole premise is I want to run a script before a default application opens

Comment: UNIX systems don't really have a concept of "default application" at all. If you're using something on top, like a specific desktop environment (KDE, GNOME, etc), then you have a question about that desktop environment.

Comment: ...that said, if you're already using `fuse`, you can always write your own FUSE overlay that implements whatever logic you happen to want. And that's a much better solution, because it's not specific to one desktop environment, or assuming that people are opening software with the "default application" (whatever that is) instead of in their editor of choice.

Comment: Your question seems ambiguous. You have a file (A). Somehow you have made a copy of it (B). Are users opening A or B? Are you wishing A or B to become readonly? After a file has been edited, how are you syncing the change back to the other file?